# symbol lookup error despite the symbol being present in linked library

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

My executable is linked against several libraries (see below), but at run-time crashes with this error:

```
symbol lookup error: bin.gcc/TestHarmonic: undefined symbol: _ZN3fmm8harmonic7details6helperILi2ENS0_6U_typeEdE5set_qEPdPKddd
```

The executable is made using (on linux, running gcc 4.8.1)

```
g++ -o bin.gcc/TestHarmonic obj.gcc/TestHarmonic.o -Llib/ -lfmm.gcc -Lutils2/lib -lWDutils2.gcc -ltbb -lCGAL -lm
```

The symbol in question is actually where it ought to be:

```
nm lib/libfmm.gcc.so | grep _ZN3fmm8harmonic7details6helperILi2ENS0_6U_typeEdE5set_qEPdPKddd
000000000a2fff0 W _ZN3fmm8harmonic7details6helperILi2ENS0_6U_typeEdE5set_qEPdPKddd
```

The library `lib/libfmm.gcc.so` is made via

```
g++ several_files.o -shared -Lutils2/lib -lWDutils2.gcc -ltbb -lCGAL -lm -o lib/libfmm.gcc.so
```

If I delete that but keep a static version `lib/libfmm.gcc.a` and build the executable again, it works. What could be wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you check with ldd that your application actually using library you built? It may find such library somewhere else in the system.

Comment: @Slava **YES** you found the problem. Indeed, `ldd` shows that I have another library of the same ****ing name, which is in the `LD_RUN_PATH` (but not the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- I'm always confused about those two) and hence found by the executable. I'm infinitely indepted to you!