# Undefined symbol mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore__

Tags: fortran, mpi, static-linking, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a Fortran program (vasp) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I was successful on an older system (13.10), but after re-installing my machine, I get a symbol lookup error:

> /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1: undefined symbol: mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore__

Strangely, the symbol seems to be actually there:

> readelf -W -s /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1 | grep "errcodes_ignore"
>
> 16: 0000000000000000 0 OBJECT GLOBAL DEFAULT UND mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore__
>       142: 0000000000000000 0 OBJECT GLOBAL DEFAULT UND mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore
>       244: 0000000000000000 0 OBJECT GLOBAL DEFAULT UND mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore_

I suspect that this may be due to the symbol being only in the static part of the library, for when I run

> readelf -W -s -D /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1 | grep "errcodes_ignore"

I don't get any result, but I'm a bit clueless on how whether this really is the problem and how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: On my system that symbol is in libmpi.so (OpenMPI 1.10).  Try adding -lmpi to your link options and see if the symbol resolves.

Comment: Thanks, but seems not to help.

Comment: There is no such thing as static part of an ELF DSO. The dynamic symbol table (a.k.a. `.dynsym` a.k.a. global symbol table) simply repeats the subset of global symbols found in the ordinary symbol table. `mpi_fortran_errcodes_ignore*` are not provided by `libmpi_f77.so.1` but rather imported from another DSO that comes with Open MPI as evident from their `UND`efined status. Why those are not present in the global symbol table is a complete mystery to me. In any case, you have to link against `libmpi.so.1` too. Make sure that it was not overwritten by another MPI version/implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation. (Did not really know how to interpret the readelf output) So far. I was not successful with linking to libmpi (added -lmpi to all linker option statements in the Makefile, but so far with no success). I added a -t option to the linker and grepped for "mpi". I get -lmpi (/usr/lib/openmpi/lib//libmpi.so)
-lmpi_f90 (/usr/lib/openmpi/lib//libmpi_f90.so)
-lmpi_f77 (/usr/lib/openmpi/lib//libmpi_f77.so)
so it should be linked to libmpi, I think. Puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this with the help of this question:
[symbol lookup error despite the symbol being present in linked library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127502/symbol-lookup-error-despite-the-symbol-being-present-in-linked-library)

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH contained a path to a different version of MPI (used for another software I am using). Changing the path before running the program resolved the issue.